# can't pass tuple to ptyhon sql query

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying this code

```
sql_account_creation_date = """UPDATE users SET account_creation_date = %s;"""
inputs_account_creation_date = (account_creation_date_entry.get(), )
print(type(inputs_account_creation_date[0]))
print(type(inputs_account_creation_date))
print(inputs_account_creation_date)
cursor.execute(sql_account_creation_date, (inputs_account_creation_date[0],) )
```

result

**<class 'str'>** 
**<class 'tuple'>** 
**('2022-06-02',)** 
**Not enough parameters for the SQL statement**

if I try with

```
cursor.execute(sql_account_creation_date, inputs_account_creation_date[0] )
```

my code returns:
**mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(2022-06-02), it must be of type list, tuple or dict**

why is my tuple converted to string (exept to tell me he doesn't like strings)?
is seems to be caused because of the date format of mysql.
I have the exact same command for other .get() but set as varchar in mysql and no issues. any idea how to .get() dates and add them with cursor.execute?
thanks for help

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong with your code, one thing you could try to narrow the problem you are facing is to try `cursor.execute(sql_account_creation_date, ('2022-06-02',) )`, and also `print(type(inputs_account_creation_date[0]))` to see what else may be amiss.

Comment: for the **print(type(inputs_account_creation_date[0]))** result is "<class 'str'>" . for **cursor.execute(sql_account_creation_date, ('2022-06-02',) )** result is" Not enough parameters for the SQL statement"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you pass the date with the index.
I cant say for sure but you need to leave the idex like:

```
cursor.execute(sql_account_creation_date, inputs_account_creation_date )
```

or you need to put it in a list:

```
cursor.execute(sql_account_creation_date, [inputs_account_creation_date[0]] )
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tryed both, and result gives "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement" . I get the date **with account_creation_date_entry = Entry(data_frame)**

Comment: okay, then it could be that you give a tulp with a null field. Can you try using a tulpe with only one field?
Since you only use one playholder it should work, but another problem could be with the conversion since you use string to look at a date

Comment: I'm pretty new to python, not sure what you are talking about. I was thinking a single tuple was like **inputs_account_creation_date = (account_creation_date_entry.get(), )**

Comment: a tulpe is basically a fixed list
because of the comma you have two field in the tulpe.